# DRBD and LVM in combination

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, lvm2

I'm wondering what is the best way to combine DRBD and LVM. Is it better to first create logical volumes and then sync them with DRBD, or is it better to use DRBD with the physical disks / partitions and then use LVM with them?

Answer (score 2):

Either way will work.

I would argue that having DRBD on LVM will give you more flexbility in terms of having things like swap and possibly other future / non-DRBD block devices. It also makes disk upgrades marginally less risky as you can snapshot before attempting a resize.

I can't see much benefit that LVM on DRBD will offer over the reverse.